# how to compute year of service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have this problem

1yr of service 15 days

3yrs of service 17 days

5yrs of service 20 days

10yrs or more of service 25 days

so come up of this code i get the year of employee hired

here's the code

```
def year_of_service(date_of_hired)
    years = [1, 3, 5, 10]
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    get_year = now.year - date_of_hired.year - ((now.month > date_of_hired.month ||
        (now.month == date_of_hired.month && now.day >= date_of_hired.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end
```

my solution here is i will use if statements but for me it will be a long code is there another solution that make it short or other possble solution

the difficulties is here how can i know if the 'get_year' is between of my array???

example:

the 'get_year' is 4 how can know that is 3 years of service not 5 but 4 is not in the array

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your method uses neither the array `years` nor the relationship between "years of service" and (15, 17, 20 or 25) "days". If those quantities are not relevant why are they there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may employ `take_while` or `select`.

```
y = [1, 3, 5, 10]                                                       

y.take_while { |i| i <= 4 }.max #=> 3
y.select { |i| i <= 4 }.last    #=> 3
```

But these involve collecting more elements than needed. Another approach is to find the index of the last element matching your criteria, then use regular array-notation to grab that element:

```
y[y.rindex { |i| i <= 4 }]       #=> 3
```

You could also use `find`, but that would involve reversing the array first. Currently there is no `rfind` in Ruby.

Comment: nice but i update my years to hash how it possible years = {1 => 15, 3 => 17, 5 => 20, 10 => 25}

Comment: how can i select the value by its key once i get the 'get_year'

Comment: @wiwit `years[y.take_while { |i| i <= 4 }.max]` should do it.